# Python converted to .exe (via Pyinstaller) doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, exe, pyinstaller

I convert a simple `print("Hello World")` code form Python to .exe with Pyinstaller (with the comand `pyinstaller -wF`) and apparently it creates the file properly. However, when I execute it, nothing happens.

Comment: My guess is that execution doesn't take long enough to see the window -- try adding a sleep and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens because `print()` sends a message to standard output (your terminal), but an .exe has no terminal. You can try to implement a GUI to display this information (in a module like `tkinter`), or have your program do something else like open a program or file on your computer!

Comment: OP says they're executing it, I assumed that meant it was being run from powershell in which case it would print to stdout

Comment: @MoxieBall I assumed `executed` meant double clicked from a file manager...I personally wouldn't create an .exe if I was running it from command line, so I figured that OP would not either. Guess they would need to clarify more in their question if they wanted a better response